# Why does the set command display more environment variables than the environment variables gui?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, cmd.exe, window

When I run the `set` command in command prompt the first variable I see is

[image]

But when I open my Environment Variables GUI I don't see `ALLUSERSPROFILE`

[image]

[image]

Why is that? There are numerous other variables listed in `set` that don't show up in the GUI as well. Shouldn't they all show the same info?

Comment: It is not uncommon on many operating systems to only include common config option in the GUI for standard users and expect that advanced users who would more likely need the less standard options will prefer the command line for their work.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of trial and error, I discovered that these environment variables
are the additional ones reported by `SET` on my Windows 8.1 system:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE
APPDATA
COMPUTERNAME
CommonProgramFiles
CommonProgramFiles(x86)
CommonProgramW6432
HOMEDRIVE
HOMEPATH
LOCALAPPDATA
LOGONSERVER
PROMPT
PUBLIC
ProgramData
ProgramFiles
ProgramFiles(x86)
ProgramW6432
SESSIONNAME
SystemDrive
SystemRoot
USERDOMAIN
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE
```

I suspect that they are all automatically generated and updated by Windows,
which is probably why I couldn't find some of them listed anywhere in Windows
Registry.

I know that `HOMEDRIVE`, `HOMEPATH` and `HOMESHARE` are [updated
automatically](//web.archive.org/web/20150511083356/support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841343) from [this TechNet Forums post](//social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e9d9cd4d-6882-459e-b7a8-7091cfa031d2/where-are-user-environment-variables-homedrive-homepath-set?forum=winserverTS).

I tried permanently changing the `PROMPT` variable to something other than
`$P$G` (which is the default) using `SETX` and noticed that it created a new
`PROMPT` environment variable in the **User variables for <username>**
section in the Environment Variables GUI.

On deleting that variable, my prompt was reset back to `$P$G`. I noticed the
same behavior with `COMPUTERNAME` environment variable. The same goes for:

```
CommonProgramFiles
CommonProgramW6432
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
ProgramFiles
ProgramW6432
```

as explained in this [MSDN article about WOW64 Implementation Details](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

According to [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (Autoexec.bat section), those variables may be *boot-time* variables, that are "not available to 32 bit gui programs". Since Windows XP, boot-time environment variables should be set with the registry in:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` *(USER environment variables)* or:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`*(SYSTEM environment variables)* 
 as shown in [Microsoft's KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/104011)